# Problems facing while installing wordpress in wamp

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost, wamp

I installed wamp and it's working fine creating the localhost and showing the green colour icon which means all processes are running.

Then I installed wordpress zip and extracted in www folder of wamp in a wordpress name folder.

But when I visited http://localhost/wordpress it shows ** error establishing connect** .

Even though I created a wordpress named database and even set a user with all previliges and then I made changes to **wp-config.php** file with this database ,user,password names .

I've even tried clearing caches but still the same thing.

Any help will be appreciated .?

Comment: Please check the port number to which WAMP is listening (is it port 80 ?)

Comment: How to check this?

Comment: WAMPServer comes with mariaDB (port3306) and MySQL(port3307) so by defeulat PHP will be connecting to mariaDB. Did you create the database in MySQL or mariaDB?

Comment: What are the contents of your htacess?